# Remove push from notificationcenter after app has been opened

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios5, notificationcenter

When I send out a PUSH notification to my app, it stays in the notification center in iOS 5.
How can I remove the notification from the notification center from within the app?

Answer (score 6):

Clearing the badge clears the notifications from the notification center.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
   // Clear application badge when app launches
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
}
```

This only works if the number changes. So to make it work in case badge is already zero, set it to  some value and clear it again after a delay.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] == 0)
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
   // Clear application badge when app launches
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
}
```

Doesn't work if you set and clear in the same method.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to remove the notification from the notification center from within the app because in iOS5, notifications properties are displayed by apps, in :

```
Settings -> Notifications -> The app -> Notification Center (YES/NO).
```

Comment: Are you sure? It seems like some apps do it.
And Apples apps does it, like Messages, Mail, etc.