# How to remove specific remote notification in the notification center

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We all know that this method `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;` could remove all remote notifications of our application from the notification center. However, for some reason, I want to remove the one which user taps on the notification center, and leave the others.

Does it have any method to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're simply looking to remove one number from the badge number:

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = MAX([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber - 1, 0);`

If you're asking how to programmatically remove a single notification from notification center, it can't be done in code. Apparently in iOS8 the OS will remove a single notification when a user taps on it. Otherwise it's not possible to be handled by you.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10569847/620577

Comment: @Don_Chen Please mark this as answered and upvote it if you believe it is the answer.

Comment: Starting iOS 10, this is possible too. Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43942760/2020490

Answer (score 8):

With introduction of `UNUserNotificationCenter` for iOS 10 and above, it is now possible to remove few or all remote notifications of your app.

> [UNUserNotificationCenter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter)

With a shared singleton instance of this class, it is possible to manage delivered remote notifications on the device. Specifically, the following methods can be used: 
`func removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [String])` if you want to remove specific notification of your app, OR `func removeAllDeliveredNotifications()` to remove all notifications of your app.