# Limit the number of iOS Remote notifications

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

is there any way to limit number of remote notification?

when i receive remote notification that has same category name, wants removing last notifications.

or, is there any way to catch notification received in background?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27591665/1818090

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove specific remote notification in the notification center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591665/how-to-remove-specific-remote-notification-in-the-notification-center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "silent" notifications.

Just enable Remote notifications background mode in capabilities.
Update notification payload by adding this to root of payload JSON:

```
"content-available" : 1
```

Then you can handle this with UNUserNotificationCenter. Check didReceiveNotificationResponse method. (Or in app delegate)

EDIT:
With this you can control when to show notification to user and numbers on application icon etc.

Comment: That's the answer I wanted. Thanks