# Swift Clear specific remote notifications

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We are currently developing an IOS application. The app should basically inform the staff member about new events/requests and the staff member has the option to cancel or accept the event (e.g. customer asks: "I d like to have a coffee", the staff member says: "okay, I'll do it" or "sorry, can't do it"). The idea is that the request appears on multiple smartphones (from multiple staff members) at the same time and that the notification has the buttons for accept/reject included.

The thing is we would like to solve this using Notifications (remote). But there is one thing which is not clear to us. Lets says I receive three requests/notifications. But until I have time to check them, on of the other staff members already resolved one of those requests. Is it possible, that this given requests can be cleared/removed from all staff members phones? Because otherwise I am handling a request that has already been resolved?

And what would be the best option to solve it.

1. Push remote notifications for every request
2. Push silent notification for every request and then clear out all notifications on the client, get the new/current requests using REST (GET) and add a local notification for every request?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Regards

Comment: and what will happen when two person open same ticket at a time(before resolving ticket).

Comment: that will be handled in our backend...

Answer (score 0):

I think second option is good.

you can refresh the data using REST api after receiving silent push.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. So you would primary work with local notifications and only use silent push notifications to fetch new data and update local notifications? Is it only possible to clear out all local notifications of the app at once (using badge:0) or is it also possible to clear out specific ones (e.g. only those wo have been resolved by another staff member)?

Comment: yes I work with it. no its not possible to clear by setting badge but you can override it by setting the same identifier as previous one

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking best option is use **Push silent notification** because end user (Application Holder) will not get clue of that and it is best for us.

Comment: could you explain this idea more in detail? how does it differ from second option?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend 1st option

- Send remote notification for every request
- Handle duplicate request from backend

I think 2nd option is not reliable

> APNs treats silent notifications as low priority and may throttle their delivery altogether if the total number becomes excessive. The actual limits are dynamic and can change based on conditions, but try not to send more than a few notifications per hour - [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)

And Individual notification can't be removed - [Check this:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10569847/620577)

Comment: Hi Shyam
Thanks for your feedback. That sounds resonable. Is it possible to override a notification by e.g. setting the same identifier as it was used by the previous notification?

Comment: @mooonli I think ur expecting Android Notification behaviour here. I don't think iOS Push Notification has any identifier in its payload. For more detail check [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html)